# Store Input to String with Python's Keyboard Library

Tags: python, input, keyboard, python-3.8

I am using the Keyboard Library in Python 3.8 (https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) and I want to save an input to a String after a space (' ') is pressed (just save it, not replay it or something else).
For example if I enter 'evening ', I want to save the word evening in a String.
Moreover I want it to read the input from the system level  keyboard and not only from python shell (no input() , raw_input() etc.)
I am a little bit lost in the documentation so any help would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this module before, but it looks like you will want to do something like this (psudeocode):

```
import queue
input_values=queue.Queue()

keyboard.start_recording(recorded_events_queue=input_values)

new_String=""
while True:
    val = input_values.get(block=True)
    if val==" ":
        break
    else:
        new_String+=val
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally did it based on your code with some modifications mainly because of the fact that val is not str but other type. I managed to xonvert it to str with a function and made it. Thanks!